# ArrayListを用いた配列の取り扱い

Tags: java

javaで配列data[任意][3]のようなものをArraylistで取り扱いたいと思うのですがどのようにすればよいでしょうか？二次元配列の方法を調べてみましたが今一つ理解できませんでした。

Comment: 例えば `List<int[]> list = new ArrayList<>();` `list.add(new int[3]);` のような形でも質問の回答になり得そうに思われますが、望んでいるものか確信できません。適切な回答を得るために(可能な範囲で)用途を追記してみてはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: SQLDBから取得したcode,name,priceの3つの値をJTableに入れたいと思っています。

Comment: `code,name,price`の3つのフィールドを持つクラス(e.g.`Product`)を定義して、それを`ArrayList<Product>()`で1次元配列(リスト)として扱う方法もありそうですね。

Answer (score 1):

SQLクエリの実行結果の1レコードを表す配列を `ArrayList` に詰める、ということであれば次の`results`のようになります。

```
final ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

final List <Object[]> results = new ArrayList<>();
while (rs.next()) {
    final Object[] r = new Object[3];

    r[0] = rs.getString(1); // code
    r[1] = rs.getString(2); // name
    r[2] = rs.getBigDecimal(3); // price

    results.add(r);
}
```

配列を使うことが必須ではないのであれば、[harry0000さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/26519/arraylist%E3%82%92%E7%94%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%9F%E9%85%8D%E5%88%97%E3%81%AE%E5%8F%96%E3%82%8A%E6%89%B1%E3%81%84#comment25321_26519)にあるように、実行結果の1レコードを表すクラスを定義してそれを用いる方法もあります。

```
public class Product {
    private String code;
    private String name;
    private BigDecimal price;

    public Product(final String code, final String name, final BigDecimal price) {
        this.code = code;
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }
    // setter/getter省略
}
```

実行:

```
final ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

final List <Product> results = new ArrayList<>();
while (rs.next()) {
    final Product r = new Product(rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getBigDecimal(3));

    results.add(r);
}
```

配列でなくクラスで扱うことのメリットとしては、取り扱うべき要素が明確になることが挙げられます。
配列の場合、code, name, priceを配列の添え字で判別する必要があったり、必要に応じて正しく`Object`型をダウンキャストする必要が出てきます。
(用途が本当に`JTable`に表示することのみであれば、そのようなメリットは必要ではないかもしれませんが。)